# How to Bind Different Lists to DataGridComboBoxColumn in each row using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I want to bind 'Units' property of ResultModel Class to DataGridComboBoxColumn. Other Bindings work fine but it cannot resolve 'Units' property. It recommends me 'Results' List instead of 'Units'. I want to use different Lists in each row.

You can see my View, ViewModel and Model Classes below.

### View.xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Width="20" Binding="{Binding Path=Count}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=ComponentName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Variable" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Property}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=PropertyValue}" />
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Unit" Width="*" ItemsSource="{Binding Units}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

### ViewModel.cs

```
private List<ResultModel> _results;

public List<ResultModel> Results
        {
            get { return _results; }
            set
            {
                _results = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Results");
            }
        }
```

### ResultModel.cs

```
private int _count;
        public int Count
        {
            get { return _count; }

            set { _count = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Count"); }
        }

        private string _componentName;
        public string ComponentName
        {
            get { return _componentName; }

            set { _componentName = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ComponentName"); }
        }

        private string _property;
        public string Property
        {
            get { return _property; }

            set { _property = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Property"); }
        }

        private double _propertyValue;
        public double PropertyValue
        {
            get { return _propertyValue; }

            set { _propertyValue = value; RaisePropertyChanged("PropertyValue"); }
        }

        private List<object> _units;
        public List<object> Units
        {
            get { return _units; }

            set { _units = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Units"); }
        }

        private Type _componentType;
        public Type ComponentType
        {
            get { return _componentType; }

            set { _componentType = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ComponentType"); }
        }
```

Comment: No 'Units' is a property of ResultModel like 'count' or 'ComponentName'. So each 'Result' in 'Results' List has its own 'Units' List

Comment: Your property name is `Unit`, but you are binding to `Units`. Fix that typo and I think it should work

Comment: I did but still not working

Comment: How do you populate "Units"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` that contained a `ComboBox` to get it to work properly. This assumes the `object` in `Units` has a `Name` property to display, you should adjust `DisplayMemberPath` accordingly.  You will pribably also want to bind `SelectedItem` to something, so you know what item they picked.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Unit">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:ResultModel">
            <ComboBox
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Units}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Unit" Width="*">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Units}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Units}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

You may also want to set the `DisplayMemberPath` property of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to the name of a property of the units.

Comment: `Cannot resolve property 'Units' in data context of type 'ViewModel'`. It still suggests me 'Results' List and the other properties in ViewModel.

Comment: Sometimes Visual Studio gets confused over what type the data context is at some points in the XAML, you can't always rely on the list it gives in intellisense.

Comment: Are you using ReShaper? Forget about these error messages then. Does it work at runtime? This is the only thing that matters.

Comment: And you don't need to use a DataGridTemplateColumn if you don't want to.

Comment: You are only supposed to see the ComboBox when the cell is in edit mode.